# image_tag not rendered from Code in Database

Tags: html, ruby, image, rendering

I have stored html code in a database field which is passed to the rails app.

```
<%= raw @exercise.explanation %>
```

The normal text is rendered correctly, it´s in the `<p> .. </p>`; but inside there the image codes are just displayed so output on the page is:

This is correct rendered text.

```
<%= image_tag ("exercises/picture.png"), style: 'height:auto; width:50%;' %>
```

Further text.

When I use `<img src="exercises/picture.png">` or `<img src="picture.png">`inside the database entry, no picture is loaded either, just the broken image symbol of the browser.

Comment: it could be the case that image source path is not correct.

Comment: the image ist located at app/assets/images/exercises and name is also correct. I tried another image in images folder, too with same results

Comment: try adding `/images/exercises/picture.png`?

Comment: already tried that before, doesn't make a change..
the problem here is not the path in my opinion, it's that the image_tag is not rendered so no matter what you type in there it is not shown 
and I am using raw so I don't understand where the problem is

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=assets+pipeline+rails+production+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Assets Pipeline on? If you do, this could happen because of the generated hash that it put on your static assets to avoid cache problems. The thing is that the `image_tag` helper resolves this. It's a trade-off, but you could disable the Assets Pipeline and see if it works. To keep it on and do this, you will need  a more elaborated solution.

You can try if it is that by disabling the assets digesting:

> config.assets.digest = false

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can have `ERB` interpret `@exercise.explanation`

```
<%= ERB.new(@exercise.explanation).result(binding) %>
```

This will take your `@exercise.explanation` and process it through `ERB` which appears to be what you are hoping for.

**Caveat**:

Be very careful what you allow to be stored in these "template" fields as things can go bad if you do not/can not sanitize this input. `ERB#result` is essentially a call to `eval` (which can be very dangerous)